# parse error syntax error unexpected end of file in closed

Tags: php

Can anyone find what is wrong with this code? i have `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\index.php on line 229` 
wondering if you can help me with this i'm so confused...

```
<?php include("./ayarlar.php");
if(isset($_GET['uygulama']) && $_GET['uygulama']=="cikis"){
$_SESSION['uyeKontrol']="";
$_SESSION['uyeTanimlama']="";
$_SESSION['uyeAdi']="";
header( 'Location: ./' );
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script id="jquery.core" src="uygulamalar/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uygulamalar/menu.js"></script>
<link href="tasarim/icon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<title><?=$sitebaslik?></title>

<style type="text/css">
ul.listemiz{width:985px;list-style:none;float:left;  padding:10px 0px 0px 23px;}
ul.listemiz li{width: 220px; height:211px; float: left; background:url(tasarim/list.png);padding:6px 18px 0px 0px;}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
ul.gorsel{width:1100px;list-style:none;float:left;  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
ul.gorsel li{width: 230px; height:143px; float: left; background:url(tasarim/tm.png);padding:6px 12px 0px 0px;}
</style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Standard/css/global.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="Standard/js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'Standard/img/loading.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true
            });
        });
    </script>



    </head>
<body style="background-attachment: scroll; background-color:#E6E6E6">
<div class="temel">
<?php include("./site01.php");?>
<div id="sayfaicerigi"><div align="center"><br />
<table border="0" width="980" height="310" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="302" valign="top" align="left">

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['uyeKontrol']) && $_SESSION['uyeKontrol']!=""){?>

        <table border="0" width="295" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="103" background="img/<?=$menu102?>.png">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="center" align="center" height="40">
                <a href="hesabim">
                <img border="0" src="img/<?=$menu108?>.png" width="120" height="32"></a>
                <a href="index.php?uygulama=cikis"> <img border="0" src="img/<?=$menu109?>.png" width="120" height="32"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center" height="33">
                <font face="Tahoma" color="#FFFFFF" style="font-size: 11pt">Hoş geldin: <?=$_SESSION['uyeAdi']?>
                </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<p><a href="emlak-ekle"><img border="0" src="img/EMLK.png" width="295" height="103"></a></p>
<?}else{?>
        <table border="0" width="295" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="103" background="img/<?=$menu102?>.png">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="center" align="center" height="40">
                <a href="kurumsal-giris">
                <img border="0" src="img/<?=$menu104?>.png" width="120" height="32"></a>
                <a href="bireysel-giris"> <img border="0" src="img/<?=$menu103?>.png" width="120" height="32"></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="center" height="33">
                <a href="uye">
                <img border="0" src="img/uyecik.png" width="244" height="23"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<p><a href="emlak-ekle"><img border="0" src="img/EMLK.png" width="295" height="103"></a></p>
<?php }?>   



        </td><td width="13"></td>
        <td width="665" valign="top" align="left">
        <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; z-index: 501" id="katman2">
        <img src="Standard/img/new-ribbon.png" width="112" height="112" alt="New Ribbon" id="ribbon">
            <div id="slides">
                <div class="slides_container">
<?php
$mansetler = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emlak order by id desc LIMIT 0,7");
while($manset = mysql_fetch_array($mansetler))
{
$mansetlerCO = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resimler where emlak='".$manset['id']."'");
if($mansetCO = mysql_fetch_array($mansetlerCO))
{
}
?>
<a href="<?=$manset['id']?>_<?=duzgundur(StrToLower($manset['emlak']))?>.html" title="" >
<div style="position: absolute; width: 595px; height: 60px; top:220px; z-index: 102; background:#C0C0C0; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; z-index:200; opacity:.8; filter:alpha(opacity=80)" id="katman3" ><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font color="#000000" face="Tahoma" style="font-size: 12pt"><?=substr($manset['emlak'],0,60)?>.. - Fiyat: <?=$manset['fiyat']?> TL</font></b></div>
<img src="<?=$mansetCO['resim']?>" width="600" height="270" alt=""></a>
<?php }?>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="Standard/img/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a>
                <a href="#" class="next"><img src="Standard/img/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a>
            </div>
            <img src="Standard/img/example-frame.png" width="739" height="341" alt="Example Frame" id="frame">
</div>
        </td>


    </tr>
</table></div>

<table border="0" width="980" height="33" style="border-bottom:1px solid #dcdbdb;">
<tr>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="35">
<img border="0" src="tasarim/icon.png" width="24" height="24"></td>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="293">
<?=$menu3?></td>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="638">
<p align="right"><a href="kiralik-konutlar"><?=$menu100?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
</tr>
</table>





    <table border="0" width="980" height="131" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" width="980">
            <ul class="gorsel">
<?php
$rastgeleler = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emlak WHERE durum=2 and onay=1 order by id desc LIMIT 8");
while($rastgele = mysql_fetch_array($rastgeleler))
{
?><li>
            <table border="0" width="238" height="113" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="14">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="115">
                    <a href="<?=$rastgele['id']?>_<?=duzgundur(StrToLower($rastgele['emlak']))?>.html">
<?php
$resimsecici = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resimler where emlak='".$rastgele['id']."'");
if($resimci = mysql_fetch_array($resimsecici))
{
?><img border="0" src="goruntule?img=<?=$resimci['resim']?>&w=110&h=91"><?}?></a></td>
                    <td width="109"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><?=$menu88?> :<?php if($rastgele['durum']==1){?><?=$menu19?><?}else{?><?=$menu20?><?php }?><br>
                    <?=$menu18?>: <?=$rastgele['fiyat']?> TL<br>
                    <?=$rastgele['ilce']?>/<?=substr($rastgele['il'],0,3)?>.<br>
&nbsp;  <br>
                    <a href="<?=$rastgele['id']?>_<?=duzgundur(StrToLower($rastgele['emlak']))?>.html">
    <img border="0" src="tasarim/<?=$menu97?>.png" width="84" height="18"></a></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </li>   <?}?>       
            </ul></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

<table border="0" width="980" height="33" style="border-bottom:1px solid #dcdbdb;">
<tr>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="35">
<img border="0" src="tasarim/icon.png" width="24" height="24"></td>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="272">
<?=$menu2?></td>
<td valign="center" align="left" width="659">
<p align="right"><a href="satilik-konutlar"><?=$menu100?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="0" width="980" height="131" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" width="980">
            <ul class="gorsel">
<?php
$rastgeleler = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emlak WHERE durum=1 and onay=1 order by id desc LIMIT 4");
while($rastgele = mysql_fetch_array($rastgeleler))
{
?><li>
            <table border="0" width="238" height="113" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="14">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="115">
                    <a href="<?=$rastgele['id']?>_<?=duzgundur(StrToLower($rastgele['emlak']))?>.html">
                    <?php
$resimsecicim = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM resimler where emlak='".$rastgele['id']."'");
if($resimcim = mysql_fetch_array($resimsecicim))
{
?><img border="0" src="goruntule?img=<?=$resimcim['resim']?>&w=110&h=91"><?}?></a></td>
                    <td width="109"><font face="Tahoma" size="2"><?=$menu88?> :<?php if($rastgele['durum']==1){?><?=$menu19?><?}else{?><?=$menu20?><?php }?><br>
                    <?=$menu18?>: <?=$rastgele['fiyat']?> TL<br>
                    <?=$rastgele['ilce']?>/<?=substr($rastgele['il'],0,3)?><br>
&nbsp;  <br>
                    <a href="<?=$rastgele['id']?>_<?=duzgundur(StrToLower($rastgele['emlak']))?>.html">
    <img border="0" src="tasarim/<?=$menu97?>.png" width="84" height="18"></a></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </li>   <?php }?>       
            </ul></td>

        </tr>
    </table>


</div>
<br>
<?php include("./site02.php");?><br><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$_SESSION['gidenemlak']="";
?>
```

Comment: i really think you could so some basic work to narrow that down

Comment: ewww, what a mess. Hence why we use frameworks and divs these days

Comment: yeea i know table is sucks but this is an old script and suddenly i have to use this script again.

Comment: What are your ideas about the possible problem?

Comment: @Tobiask You are not the first to attempt this edit. It has been reverted once (by the OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is this piece: `}?>` Which is located somewhere in the middle of the code.

You shouldn't put brackets directly close to the open/close php tag, but separate with space: `} ?>`

Comment: yeap.thank you,i solve the problem. all change all,and solved.

Comment: @user1787955 well if this helped you, you might as well consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because of lacking space between open/close php tag and brackets. You should avoied this:

```
{?> AND <?}else{?>
```

Instead, you should have it like this:

```
{ ?> AND <?php else{ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some ending curly brackets in your script